# Sitecore Content Editor Search is behaving unusual for items with SPACE

Tags: solr, content-search

We have the following issue with `SC9.3` `Solr 8.1.1`
A Media item with sample name "Text_20230101 Hello world". We have the below behavior in the CMS content editor search. (free text search on the left side in the content editor)

| Search Text | Result |
| --- | --- |
| Text_20230101 Hello world | Found |
| Text_20230101 Hello wor | No Result |
| Text_20230101 Hello[Space] | Found |
| Text_20230101 Hello | Found |
| Text_20230101 He | No Result |
| Text_20230101 | Found |
| Text_2023 | Found |
| Text_ | Found |
| Text | Found |

We are using the Standard Tokenizer for text_general fields. Here is a screenshot from managed-schema

[image]

Is this the OOTB behavior for the Sitecore CMS content editor search?
Is there any other tokenizer that would provide the expected search results for the use cases mentioned above?

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that it's exactly the same in default setup of Sitecore 10.x.

Query that is being generated is like:

```
(_name:("Text_20230101 Hello wor\*") OR (_content:("\*Text_20230101 Hello wor\*") AND _language:(en)))
```

and if you don't have spaces in your query it looks like

```
(_name:(Text_20230101*) OR (_content:(*Text_20230101*) AND _language:(en)))
```

With `"` characters around the search text and escaped `*`, your query for name matching doesn't work.

You can create Sitecore support ticket or add your own processor to `<search>` pipeline:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/"  xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
    <sitecore role:require="Standalone or ContentManagement">
        <pipelines>
            <search>
                <processor type="MyAssemly.MyNamespace.MySearchProcessor, MyAssemly" patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.ContentSearch.Client.Pipelines.Search.SearchContentSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Client']"/>
            </search>
        </pipelines>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

and either add extra logic there or completely replace existing `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Client.Pipelines.Search.SearchContentSearchIndex` processor.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs  Marek, I shall try both (support ticket and pipeline) and update here upon resolution.